# Wrong output using the Runtime Stack Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was working on this little application, but came across this problem. I have created 3 classes,

1) ARFib

```
int n; // parameter
int t1, t2; // temp vars
int returnVal;
static int count = 0;

void fib() {
    count++;

    if (n <= 1) {
        returnVal = 1;
     } 
     else {
        ARfib newARfib = new ARfib();
        newARfib.n = n - 1;
        RuntimeStack.push(newARfib);
        newARfib.fib();
        t1 = newARfib.returnVal;
        RuntimeStack.pop();
        returnVal = n + t1;

        newARfib.n = n - 2;
        RuntimeStack.push(newARfib);
        newARfib.fib();
        t1 = newARfib.returnVal;
        RuntimeStack.pop();
        returnVal = t1 + t2;
        //RuntimeStack.display();

    }
}
```

2) RuntimeStack Implementation

```
public class RuntimeStack {

static Nodes top; // this represents the top element of the stack
static int size; // this represents the size of the stack

// to add element to the stack
public static void push(AR newAR) {
    Nodes n = new Nodes(newAR);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        top = n;
        size++;
    } else {

        n.setNext(top);
        top = n;
        size++;
    }

}

// to get data from the stack
public static void pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
    } else {
        // AR value = top.getData();
        Nodes temp = top;
        top = top.getNext();
        temp.setNext(null);
        size--;
        // return;
    }

}

// to check if stack is empty
public static boolean isEmpty() {
    if (top == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

    public static void display() {
    Nodes temp = top;

    while (temp != null) {

        System.out.println(temp.getData());
        System.out.println();
        temp = temp.getNext();
        if (top == null) {
            System.out.println(top);
        }
    }
```

3) MainFib

```
public abstract class MainFib {
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    // argv[0]: output file

    Output.setOutput(argv[0]);
    ARfib ex = new ARfib();

     ex.n=10;
    RuntimeStack.push(ex);
    if (ex.n == 0)
        RuntimeStack.display();
    ex.fib();
    System.out.println("The total number of function calls so far = " + ex.count);
    System.out.println();
    RuntimeStack.display();
    System.out.println(ex.toString());

    System.out.println(ex.returnVal);
    RuntimeStack.pop();
    Output.closeOutput();
  }

}
```

However I am not getting the desired output. Below is the desired output.

```
  -----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 11
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:
ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 15
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 19
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 25
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 29
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 35
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 39
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 43
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 51
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 55
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0``
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 59
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 65
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 69
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 77
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 81
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 85
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 91
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 95
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 101
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 105
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 109
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 9 t1 = 21 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 119
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 123
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 127
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 133
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 137
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 143
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 147
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 151
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 7 t1 = 8 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 159
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 163
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 167
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 5 t1 = 3 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 173
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 3 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
The total number of function calls so far = 177
The maximum stack size so far = 10

The contents of the runtime stack will be displayed from top to bottom:

ARfib n = 0 t1 = 0 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 2 t1 = 1 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 4 t1 = 2 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 6 t1 = 5 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 8 t1 = 13 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
ARfib n = 10 t1 = 34 t2 = 0 returnVal = 0
```

This is my output

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ucUv.png)

I don't want the code, but I am just looking for some guidance or where is my code going wrong. The ARFib class gives me the right value and function calls, just in a messed up order...

Comment: two observations: in the desired output the bottom of the stack is always "ARfib n = 10...", and the top of the stack is always "ARfib n = 0...". Maybe your main should calculate not ARfib from 1 to 10, but only ARfib(10). And maybe your stack class should print it's contents anytime the pushed ARfib has `n==0`

Comment: Ok, I did this: if(top == null) {
    System.out.println(top);
    
   } @ThomasKläger

Comment: That's not what I expected. I would have expected (at the end of `push()`: `if (newAR.n == 0) display();`

Comment: All done, but it's still not giving me the right output.

Answer (score 0):

I would write

```
public class RuntimeStack {
    //...
    public static void push(AR newAR) {
        Nodes n = new Nodes(newAR);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            top = n;
            size++;
        } else {
            n.setNext(top);
            top = n;
            size++;
        }
        if (newAR.n == 0) 
            display();
    }
    //...
}
```

For me this already gives almost the correct output